# Semisimplicity and global dimension

Tags: semi-simple-rings, global-dimension

I know this could be a dumb question, but I've been studying for hours and I might be too tired to see why:

**A ring R is semisimple if and only if its global dimension is zero.**

We define the global dimension of a ring as g|dim(R):=Sup{pd(M)} where M is a module finitely generated of R and pd(M) is the projective dimension of M.
I already know that :

"A ring is semisimple if and only if all of its modules are projective"

which could be very useful here, but I cant see how to prove any direction of the first statement. Thanks for advance.

Comment: Your formulation is a bit confusing. How do you define global dimension? Do you know already that a ring is s.s. i.f.f. all modules are projective, or you don't know how to show it? Do you know that a ring has zero global dimension i.f.f. all modules are projective, or not?

Comment: @Sasha I'm so sorry, you where right, I already reformulate it.

Comment: Isn't it tautological? If R is semisimple then all modules are projective, and therefore projective dimension of every module is 0. Conversely, if projective dimension of every f.g. module is 0 then every f.g. module is semisimple, and thus every module is semisimple... Maybe you don't know that projective dimension of a module is 0 i.f.f. the module is projective?

Comment: your last sentence was the key, I didn't know it. Thanks

Comment: I completely ignored that intituively the projective dimension of a module is how far is it to be projective.